# Katalon - Executing test suite in a test suite setup method?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, functional-testing, katalon-studio

I'm trying to build a test hierarchy where other test suites are executed so a new test suite picks up where the last suite left off. Is there some way I can run a test suite execution in the set up of my test suite?

```
@SetUp(skipped = false)
def setUp() {
    // execute test suite here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write to a file in a teardown method of the first test suite, and read from the same file in the setup method of the next test suite.

My first idea was to use Global Variables to do that, but they are relevant only inside of a [single test suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427982/katalon-when-is-a-globalvariable-reset).