# Katalon: When is a GlobalVariable reset?

Tags: automated-tests, global-variables, katalon-studio

When using Katalon and changing the values of a GlobalVariable during, before or after a test case or test suite, when exactly does the changes reset to the defined value in the profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the GlobalVariables is reset to default on the teardown of the test suite (or the teardown of a test case when a single test case is run).

For example, if you have `GlobalVariable.x=1` set in the Global Variables and you have `GlobalVariable.x=2` line in your test case, after the test case ends, x is reset to 1.